# jQuery Left Right Slider With Fade

Tags: jquery, slider

I need some sort of jQuery slider. Exactly what I need is: It will be three slides, with slide 2 being centered on the page when it loads. Slide 1 to the left and slide 3 to the right will only be partially visible, since the edge of the site container will cut part of them off, plus I would like to have them fade out, giving the user a hint that there is more content. Anyone know of any jQuery plugins out there that would make this easy? Hopefully this makes sense...I've attached a simple sketch of what I'm talking about. Thanks all!

[image: Example Sketch]

Answer (score 1):

[Infinite Carousel](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/). Check out the demos. You can hint at the previous and next images and much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely achieve this by making some modifications to [Basic jQuery Slider](https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider) (*Full disclosure: I developed this plugin myself*). If you us it in 'slide' mode and then modify the main container to be slighly wider than required (thus showing the edges of the previous and next slides) and overlay a div, with a transparent png gradient at either end to give the faded effect on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is finished work rather than an answer to a question.

You can develop this yourself, or you can find a pre-made jQuery gallery on one of several software sites.  Try http://codecanyon.com if you have a little spending dough for the project (usually $10 to $20).

Comment: Wasn't asking for finished work, just some hints in the right direction :) I'll look at codecanyon, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of slide show plugins for jQuery, one example that seems to fit your needs would be [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/). Haven't used this particular plugin but it would probably be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
            startAtElementId: "startAtMe", 
            visibleHotSpots: "always"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant give you a pre made plugin but I ca give you an idea of how this could be done.

Use CSS to do the fading on the left and right sliders. Change there classes when they are not the main content. See sliding scripts from one of the above projects and build this on your own. The feeling of making something yourself is a bliss!

I would add that to make your site efficient . you should probably load the contents in an array of lets say 10 or so, display 3 at a time. and when you've seen something like 6 elements, make an AJAX query and fill the array again. This way, your widgets will look great and the performance will be splended. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple and could be personalized easily http://oslide.andresbott.com/